Convert a python UDF to pandas UDF to improve performance in PySpark
I have multiple functions in Python that I am using as UDFs in PySpark, but the problem is that my data is too big, and applying all these UDFs takes a long time to complete the transformation. The syntax for all the UDFs is the same. I have heard that Pandas UDFs are a lot faster than Python UDFs. I tried to apply them to my code, but since I have not much experience which Pandas, I have been getting a lot of errors.
Python UDF is as follows:
def python_udf(row):
    if row is None:
        return '[]'
    x = json.dumps(yaml.safe_load("".join(row.split('""'))))
    return json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(x.replace('"', '')))

The Pandas UDF I tried to generate:
@pandas_udf(returnType=StringType())
def python_udf(row):
    if row is None:
        return '[]'
    x = json.dumps(yaml.safe_load("".join(row.str.split('""'))))
    return json.dumps(yaml.safe_load(x.replace('"', '')))

The syntax for input of this function is:
"[{""abc"": ""abc"", ""def"": ""18"", ""ghi"": 3, ""jkl"": 0, ""mno"": []}]"

I would really appreciate if someone could help me how to change my current UDFs to use as Pandas UDF.
Using the same function with pandas_udf gave me error stating Type Mismatch 'expected str got list'.

Original Python UDF
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

# Define the UDF
def multiply_by_two(x):
    return x * 2

# Register the UDF
multiply_by_two_udf = udf(multiply_by_two, DoubleType())

# Use the UDF
df = df.withColumn('result', multiply_by_two_udf(df['input_column']))

Converted to Pandas UDF:
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
import pandas as pd

# Define the Pandas UDF
@pandas_udf(DoubleType())
def multiply_by_two(x: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return x * 2

# Use the Pandas UDF
df = df.withColumn('result', multiply_by_two(df['input_column']))

Grouped Map Pandas UDF Original Python UDF:
def calculate_mean(df):
    return df.agg({"value": "mean"})

df.groupby('group').apply(calculate_mean)

Converted to Grouped Map Pandas UDF:
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, DoubleType, StringType
import pandas as pd

# Define the schema for the result
schema = StructType([
    StructField('group', StringType(), True),
    StructField('mean_value', DoubleType(), True)
])

# Define the Pandas UDF
@pandas_udf(schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def calculate_mean(pdf: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    mean_value = pdf['value'].mean()
    result = pd.DataFrame({'group': [pdf['group'].iloc[0]], 'mean_value': [mean_value]})
    return result

# Use the Pandas UDF
df.groupby('group').apply(calculate_mean)

